# SQL - How to find a record that contains only 1 value in a field

Tags: sql, select

I have a table that can look like this:

```
member       value
0001         1
0001         2
0001         3
0002         1 
0002         2
0003         1
```

essentially what I need to do is retrieve member 3 as they only have a record with a value of 1. Member 2 has records with values of 1 and 2 and member 3 has records with values 1, 2 and 3.

Please help!

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Please post your code you tried so far and your tables in sqlfiddle.

Comment: I would ask that the tables get posted in the original question.  StackOverflow's questions will persist for years, but we have no way of knowing how long sqlfiddle postings will still be available.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Transact-SQL

```
SELECT member, value
  FROM TableName
  WHERE value IN
  (SELECT value FROM TableName
   GROUP BY value
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

If there is more than one member with a single entry it finds them all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` with a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT t.member, t.value
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE value = 1
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
    WHERE t2.value <> 1
    AND   t.member = t2.member
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ba2d/3/0)</kbd>

If you use MS Sql-Server `NOT EXISTS` is also the most efficient approach which has no issues on nullable columns. Worth reading: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 0):

```
select member
from (
select '0001' as member, 1 as value
union
select '0001' as member, 2 as value
union
select '0001' as member, 3 as value
union
select '0002' as member, 1 as value
union
select '0002' as member, 2 as value
union
select '0003' as member, 1 as value
) members
group by member
having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of complex answers as of time of posting but the question can be answered quite simply using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select member
  from members_values
 group by member
having count(value) = 1
```

You haven't mentioned what RDBMS you're using but AIUI, the above code should be ANSI compatible; it also assumes your table is called something like `members_values`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking to find the `member` that only exists once in that table...

The following query groups by `member` and proves the number of times that `member` appears in the table

```
SELECT member
     , Count(*) As number_of_apperances
FROM   your_table
GROUP
    BY member
```

Now we use the `HAVING` clause to limit this aggregate to show only those records who appear just once:

```
SELECT member
     , Count(*) As number_of_apperances
FROM   your_table
GROUP
    BY member
HAVING Count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT member
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY member
HAVING COUNT(value) = 1
```